# Fail to launch a app on genymotion manualy

Tags: android, mobile, genymotion

After successfully installing app on genymotion on manually opening the app is failing to launch showing a error pop up , What might be the reason and how to fix it ?

Comment: what is error shown in popup?

Comment: Show your Log-cat error.

Comment: @Rajesh Jadav error is App-name has stopped

Comment: @vrund where to find the log ??

Comment: Open window > show view > LogCat or Open window > show view > others > Android > LogCat